# Making a minimalistic build file for a Qt-using application from scratch

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

For pure educational purposes, I'd like to learn how to create my own QT Makefile from scratch.

I've used QMake successfully, but I still would like to learn how to make an extremely simple Makefile to run a basic QT application.

Here is my code that I want to compile with the Makefile:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow m;

    m.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I don't have any special requirements and do not need any special native packaging.

Comment: Why not just make a .pro file, then run qmake, then look at the Makefile that qmake generated, and base your own Makefile on that one?

Comment: I had a difficult time understanding what was necessary within the generated Makefile.

Comment: You don't have to understand what's necessary - you can start pruning it and figure it out that way by following a mechanical process. You do need to understand how makefiles work and that's about all.

Comment: What are: target, build platform, compiler, make tool? The answers will heavily depend on that. You'll also note that your "minimalistic" makefile will not really be much smaller than the one qmake generated. qmake isn't there to make your life hard or to produce lots of unnecessary junk :)

Comment: I somehow doubt in the educational value of such an endeavor.

Comment: I had the same interest as the OP and did exactly what @JeremyFriesner has suggested in the first comment.  Did it once or twice by hand and then realized that  the beauty of qmake is that it generates a set of makefiles specific for the current OS. The significance of this is subtle but not to be underestimated - especially considering that the Qt library is platform independent. Now I do not add the makefiles generated by qmqke to the source code repository but add only the .pro file. So, follow the advise in the first comment and keep trying. It is not that hard  and worth the effort.

Comment: Please, use CMake and spare others from dealing with different build systems. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/qt/1991/cmakelists-txt-for-your-qt-project

Comment: Good advice, @BradS.

So, since yesterday, I've gotten much closer.

[Here is my progress so far.](https://ghostbin.com/paste/8rqsr)

It successfully compiles to an executable without errors. However, when I type `./a.out`, [I get this error](https://ghostbin.com/paste/h898z).

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Never mind. Figured it out and created a very minimal Makefile. Will be posting an answer with my final Makefile. I made sure to provide comments to describe each line. Would love to hear your guys opinion on it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes! That was a heck of a learning experience. :)

Here is the minimal Makefile I created.

```
# In the first two lines, I define the source (.cpp) file and the desired output file to be created (./hello)
SOURCE = hello.cpp
OUTPUT = hello

# This variable is used as a quick reference to the QT install path. This is my custom install directory on Mac OS X.
QT_INSTALL_PATH = /usr/local/qt/5.9.1/clang_64

# This is where you would provide the proper includes depending on your project's needs
INCLUDES = -I$(QT_INSTALL_PATH)/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers

#This is the RPATH. To be honest, I am not completely sure of what it does, but it is neccesary.
RPATH = -Wl,-rpath,$(QT_INSTALL_PATH)/lib

#Here is where you link your frameworks
FRAMEWORKS = -F$(QT_INSTALL_PATH)/lib -framework QtCore -framework QtWidgets

# The main action that happens when you type "make"
all:
    # We run the g++ command and make sure we use c++11 with the second argument. Then after that, we simply plugin in our previous variables.
    g++ -std=c++11 $(SOURCE) $(INCLUDES) $(FRAMEWORKS) $(RPATH) -o $(OUTPUT)
```

And in case you are wondering, here is my `hello.cpp` file. It's a very basic program that only imports `QtWidgets`.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget window;
    window.resize(320, 240);
    window.show();
    window.setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("toplevel", "Welcome to QT!"));
    return app.exec();
}
```

This was a lot of fun and I definitely learned a lot about how QT programs are compiled. However, in the future I definitely plan on sticking to qmake, as it's a really great tool.

Comment: One of the strongest Qt features is that it is cross-platform. Your `Makefile` not only macos-specific, it has hardcoded path to Qt installation directory.

Comment: Yep. I do not intend to use this in any projects.